# ASP.NET MVC5 Entity Framework Group Fields (Country, State) for Account

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Company, Country and State classes.
State is related to Country
State and Country are foreign key to Company

The problem Company View shows both state and Country as separate dropdowns.
**But I expect when I select State, corresponding Country should change or vice versa**. Is this possible in MVC5 EF Model.

### Company Class

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100,MinimumLength=3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int? StateID { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
    public int? CountryID { get; set;}
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public int CompanyTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyType CompanyType { get; set; }

}
```

Country Class

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

State Class

```
public class State
{
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }

}
```

I have scaffolded and Generated the view and Company View for reference

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Company</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateID, "StateID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("StateID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryID, "CountryID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CountryID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyTypeID, "CompanyTypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CompanyTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div> } <div> @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

@section Scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need are Cascading Dropdown Lists.  Here is an example from CodeProject.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258172/Simple-Implementation-of-MVC-Cascading-Ajax-Drop-D

Comment: Thanks, Whether there is any possibility, to group these two properties in Model and Controller, So that Visual studio can generate the code for me.

Comment: No.  You'll need to write the code.  HTML controls have no concept of dependence as others have pointed out

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible in MVC5 EF Model.

Yes. But you'll need to do the work (or get (buy) controls that do it for you).

The limitation is not MVC, but that the default HTML controls have no concept of being dependent on another. Either write code to change the content of the State drop down when the Country drop down changes (this could include filtering the list of states by the selected country), or get thirdy party controls that do so (it is a common requirement so lots of controls out there<sup>1</sup>).

---

<sup>1</sup> But [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) does not do recommendations of tools.

Comment: I am not looking to use third party controls. So only option is to do this manually in View or is there any workaround